# laravel eloquent relationship from query builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

If I do this, I would be able to retrieve the `images()` for the `item`

```
$items = Item::all();
foreach($items as $item){
    $image = $item->images()->first();
}
```

However if I had a complex query using the query builder. I wouldn't be able to get the `images()` from it. Is there a way to get all the relationship data from the Eloquent Models considering this is a query builder?

```
$items = DB::table('items as i')
    ->join('users AS u', 'i.user_id', '=', 'u.id')
    ->where('account_id', 5)->all();        
foreach($items as $item){
    $image = $item->images()->first();
}
```

**Item Model**

```
class Item extends Eloquent {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'items';

    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Image');
    }

    public function user(){

        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

}
```

**Image model**

```
class Image extends Eloquent {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'images';

    public function item(){

        return $this->belongsTo('Item');
    }

}
```

**UPDATED: Added User Model**

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';


    public function items()
    {
        // foreign key outside using this pk
        return $this->hasMany('Item');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't actually executed the query. Add get(), all() or first()

Additionally, you won't actually be returning an eloquent model so won't be able to use eloquent relationships. You can just add fluent queries to eloquent though. Try this:

```
$items = Item::join('users AS u', 'i.user_id', '=', 'u.id')
              ->where('account_id', '=', 5)
              ->all();       
foreach($items as $item){
    $image = $item->images()->first();
}
```

Comment: yes sorry I forgot to add `all()` while copy pasting because I had a series of `->where()` . This works for `$item->images()->first()` but does not work for `$item->user->name` any ideas? I get an error `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: $item->user()->first()->name

Comment: I updated my models. I only have 1 user per Item and `$item->user->name` works if I simply do `$item = Item::all();` . Do you have any ideas?

Comment: are you sure? Without seeing your model I can't tell, but seems unlikely that $item->user->name would work from $item = Item::all(); The reason is that $item->user should return an eloquent attribute. This is usually a string. So $item->user->name is trying to call an object property of a string, which will throw an error - Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: if you are trying to get the user name of an item, the only way i can see it working is this - $item->user()->first()->name