# How can I use taxItem and Uom inside the if block

Tags: mysql, laravel

How can I use `taxItem` and `Uom` inside the `if` block?

```
Table: product
      product_items
      product_taxes
      vendors
      product_uoms

$results = Product::with('taxItem','uom')
$results = DB::table('products')
```

How should I add `with()` in query builder?

```
 public function search(Request $request)
        {
            $request->validate([
                'vendor_id' => 'sometimes|required|integer|exists:vendors,id'
            ]);
            if(request()->has('vendor_id')) {        
                $results = DB::table('products')        
                    ->select(
                      ......
                    )        
                    ->join('product_items', 'products.id', '=', 'product_items.product_id')
                    ->join('vendors', 'vendors.id', '=', 'product_items.vendor_id')
                    ->where('product_items.vendor_id', '=', request('vendor_id'))

                    ->where(function($query) {...
                    })

                    ->limit(6)
                    ->get();
            } 
            else {
                $results = Product::with('taxItem','uom')
                   ....          
            }
            return api([
                'results' => $results
            ]);
        }
```

Comment: `$results = Product::with(['taxItem','uom'])->where('vendor_id', request()->vendor_id)->get();`

Also you need to have relationships "taxItem" & "uom" defined in your `Product` model.

Comment: Thanks for the return. However, this was not the solution.
My expectation is to apply the working relationship in the else block to the if block as well: $ results = DB :: table ('products') and join tables are required
(Solution must be with Query Builder. Or a different solution) I hope google translate it towards.

Comment: Might this be any of any help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21874390/laravel-eloquent-relationship-from-query-builder